# can some one help me for set my amp for j-rock?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects

I have started playing 1 week ago. I don't understand how to completely set my amp. Can some one help me for set my amp for j-rock?

I use blackstar id core 10. I use blackstar's amp software for amp settings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tonereport.com](https://tonereport.com/uploads/img/blackstar-insider-software.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Please define j-rock?

Comment: I believe that j-rock is Japanese rock.

Comment: @MrTheBard: Correct, but that's a pretty large genre. The OP might need to be more specific in terms of what exactly they are trying to achieve.

Comment: @grumtaku, sounds like a good question for the Blackstar INSIDER community. Not sure, were the hid it, but you probably can find more insiders here: https://forum.blackstaramps.com/index.php .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what J-Rock is definitively as it could mean a number of things, however if you mean a 'metal' style rock guitar sound that I believe to be popular over there, then it can be quite simple:

- Strip all of your pedals and effects, and turn all dials to zero;
- Turn the volume up as far as it will go;
- Keep the Bass and Treble dials high;
- Turn down any 'Middle' dials until the sound becomes
  scooped - bear in the mind that middle frequencies are important for
  clarity, so find a decent compromise;
- Bring up the gain until you get the sound you require;
- Finally, bring the volume down to a more manageable level.

This will get you a lot of the way, but without any clearer description of what you want to sound like, then I can't offer any more help.